# Abstract base class virtual pure method that takes itself as a parameter

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++17, virtual-functions, abstract-base-class

Apologies for any poor wording, I'm not quite sure how to express the question.

I have a base class A, which has a pure virtual operator+= which takes an instance of itself. In the derived class B I'd like to override operator+= of the base class such that it takes an instance of B (rather than A).

```
// Abstract base class
template <class T>
class A
{
    A() = default;

    virtual A<T>& operator+=(const A&) = 0;
}

// Derived class
template <class T>
class B : public A<T>
{
   T some_field = 3.14159;

   B(const T x) : A(), some_field(x) {}

   B<T>& operator+=(const B& b) override
   {
       this.some_field += b.some_field;

       return (*this);
   }
}
```

I do understand why this doesn't work; the two methods are different functions because they expect different arguments. However, I assume that there must be some way to guarantee that any class derived from A will implement operator+= in which it takes an instance of the derived class as the argument.

```
virtual operator+=(const <this_class_type>&) = 0;
```

Please could you offer a solution to this? Thanks very much!

Comment: I daresay you haven't considered it carefully enough. Ponder the Liskov substitution principle. You don't intend to have support for adding a general `A` to a `B`, but that's exactly the contract that `A` specifies and you try to get around.

Comment: Yes I realise that's what the above code would actually do, I was hoping it would just help clarify what my intention was :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be using `T` for the parameter:

```
template<typename T>
class IBase
{
public:
    virtual IBase& operator+=(const T& Instance) = 0;
};

class CDerived : IBase<CDerived>
{
public:
    IBase& operator+=(const CDerived&) override
    {
        return *this;
    }
};

class COtherDerived : IBase<COtherDerived>
{
public:
    IBase& operator+=(const COtherDerived&) override
    {
        return *this;
    }    
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    CDerived Derived1, Derived2;
    Derived1 += Derived2;
    COtherDerived Derived3;
    // Derived3 += Derived1; <-- Will not compile
}
```

Comment: Doh! Don't know why I didn't think of this. Thanks for the explanation, makes a lot more sense to me now. I still require T to be a primitive type so I've added another template parameter to the base class to hold the derived class type. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, your initial code sample did not show for what you are using `T` so, I was not sure if you need one or two template types, but as we can see you got around it:)

Comment: What's the point of having a base class when all the derived classes would have different bases? In this exmaple you can remove the base class completely and you would have the exact same result.

Comment: @super - the base class imposes a contract that the derived classes should implement. I think that is what the author is trying to achieve. With the base you can gave templated code working with `IBase`.

Comment: Sorry I should have made it more clear that derived class B was meant to contain a primitive type (T) which was not an instance of the class.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis So the only purpose of the base class is to force any derived classes to implement certain methods? That makes some sense I guess.

Comment: Well it's just an example, but yes in this case. As a general question, is it preferable to post a simplified example of the problem, or the full class with all of the context in question? I've always thought the former, but I can see how that leads to problems where context was not made clear enough.

Comment: @user7119460 your example was generally fine:) If it would not be, I would not be able to answer:D